# Eight foreign keys to the same table

Tags: database-design

Maybe, I'm getting crazy and finally I've forgotten everything I learned but I have a lot of doubt about a database model that I'm designing.

This is my problem:

I have a table with n columns, eight columns of them will have three possible values: YES, NO, UNKNOWN.

I've thought that I could use another table with a PK and a description, but I'm not sure if I can create eight foreign keys from one table to the same table.

My question is:

Do I need a second table to store YES, NO and UNKNOWN? Is it possible to have eight foreign keys to the same table?

Comment: Of course it's possible, although have you considered ENUM?

Comment: Your database may vary? I notice that none of your abstract questions about databases mention what DB you're using. This is probably relevant. (MySQL and postgreql both have ENUMs.)

Comment: It's a database design for SQL Server 2008 and Sql lite for Android. I'm going to use an Enum on software side or probably I'm going to store YES, NO and UNKNOWN as text.

Comment: For example MySQL comes with both an ENUM and a SET type for columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not crazy.

There is a way of modeling data that ends up with tables that function as hubs,  with many other tables referencing these hubs via the FK/PK mechanism.  The design is called "star schema".  The tables that act as hubs are called "fact tables".  The tables that reference them are called "dimension tables".  There is another design called "snowflake schema"  where dimension tables are themselves referenced by other tables.

You can't design a schema that is both star and normalized.  They are two different disciplines, each with its best area of applicability.  Star schemas are good for data warehouses, data marts, and reporting databases.  Generating complex analytical queries turns out to be surprisingly easy.  Updating a star schema is a royal pain.  For that reason a normalized design works better when you are doing OLTP.

Star schema was originally developed as a way of moving so called "multidimensional modeling" into the world of SQL databases.  Multidimensional modeling is used in structures like data cubes from Cognos and others.

However, the design goals of star schema are very different from the ones you outline in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need a second table to store YES, NO and UNKNOWN?

Not really. Why not just use the "bool" (or "bit" etc...) type provided by the DBMS, with values such as TRUE (or 1 or whatever), FALSE (or 0) and NULL?

Alternatively, consider a simple INT where each value is documented and "well-known" to all clients. Or an ENUM if the DBMS supports it (MySQL). Please don't use string for what is logically a Boolean or enumeration - you'll end up wasting space on many repeated strings.

I'd consider separate table(s) only if:

- values need to be dynamic (i.e. user can add new values)
- or you need to provide additional information (such as description or comment) for each of the values.

> Is it possible to have eight foreign keys to the same table?

It is possible for the same table to be a parent endpoint of eight foreign keys. It is also possible (though *smelly*) for the same table to be a child endpoint of eight FKs.

So yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is, without doubt, possible to have eight foreign keys in a design (but there might be some RDBMS out there that won't allow it) but I do wonder which problem domain you are modelling if you see this as the solution.

Foreign keys describe a relation where the table with the foreign key will contain records that depend on records in the referenced table. To have eight references to keep track of a one to one relation between records in two tables seems a bit odd.

Especially since the columns can have only three values. Which relation would that express? How many records in the referenced table can be indicated?

Without more details, I'd say your design is broken.

Comment: Someone has suggested me to use an ENUM.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly okay to have foreign keys as you describe. Try it.

ENUM's are fine too of course, as long as you will never have more states to deal with (e.g. "maybe"), or need to move to a different database that may not support enum's.

Comment: Hmm, just to put this on a slightly more justified footing. The pattern which involves a lot of references to a few values is the "Flyweight Pattern", and is entirely legitimate, even encouraged. It is evidence of a strong design. I would mark it higher than use of enum's or encoded values. It enhances data integrity and is completely standard (unlike enum's). It is also less risky in that it can accommodate change. So, from a pure data design point of view, it is the preferable solution, as weird as it may seem.